# Deactive overwrite in Expo Snack

Tags: react-native, expo

I am programming in Expo Snack.io and the overwrite feature got activated somehow.

How can I deactivate the overwrite of code and have it normal?

Answer (score 0):

just update the expo sdk at the bottom right, the latest one today is expo sdk 30.1